# with vue.js, how to properly deal with vue-unmanaged dom elements

Tags: vue.js

I need some advice about handling vue components through DOM nodes that are not under the control of vue, for example, mounting a vue component on an element created by v-html.

eg.

```
<vue-main-component>
    <vue-component-A>
        <unmanaged-dom-nodes...> // issued by v-html
            <...>
                <vue-component-B>
```

Obviously, vue cannot create `vue-component-B` automatically.
However, `vue-component-A` is able to create and mount `vue-component-B` once `unmanaged-dom-nodes` are rendered.

Currently I use a quite straightforward technique:
When `vue-component-A` is mounted, I detect elements that needs to become vue components in `unmanaged-dom-nodes` through `data-xxx` attributes, using `querySelectorAll('[data-xxx]')`

```
    // parentVm is the vm of vue-component-A
    // componentClass is vue-component-B
    const vm = new (Vue.extend(componentClass))({
        parent: parentVm,
    })

    parentVm.$once('hook:destroyed', () => void vm.$destroy());
    domNode.appendChild(vm.$mount().$el);
```

Currently this work as expected, however I wondering if it is possible to make it more robust.

Use cases:

- a 3rd party dashboard that is not based on vue.js, and that allow html content
- a rich text editor that may accept vue components as content

Comment: How do you define an unmanaged DOM node? A <div> in a component's template or an element created dynamically with a JS library/directly by manipulating the DOM with JS?

Comment: Indeed, what does "unmanaged DOM node" even mean? Your template (or render function) for `<vue-component-A>` can simply include any valid HTML elements or Vue components, in whatever hierarchy is appropriate. It sure looks like you're making something super complicated that is, in fact, super easy.

Comment: In fact, I do not have the control of these unmanaged-dom-nodes. (I have added some use cases in the question).